Definition of 出元
I'm confused about the definition of 出元 in the following excerpt (original formatting preserved):

爆発した２機の
残骸から出元を
調べたが
機体は両方とも
修理センターから
盗まれたものだったよ
Source: https://www.streetfighter.com/6/comics/ja-jp/story4.html, page 5

The source I saw it in comes with an official translation, but it's pretty loose and basically ignores the first sentence entirely.
From the context I assume that 出元 means "origin", but I can't find an entry for it in any of the dictionaries I've checked. Is it an uncommon word, a neologism, and/or slang?

Sanseidou defines it as それが出てくる、おおもとのところ.

^ 「三省堂国語辞典」ですね。「明鏡国語辞典」にも「コトバンク」にも「Weblio国語辞書」にも載ってませんわ・・　普通「[出所]{でどころ}」って言うのかな

@JimmyYang Thanks! If I might ask, what reading does Sanseido say to use for it? (As usual, ChatGPT pretends to know the answer but gives a different reading when I ask it a second time....)

でもと. Also, I'd avoid ChatGPT like a plague for Japanese if I were you.

@JimmyYang Appreciate it! Yeah, I only use ChatGPT when I can't think of any better option, and even then I don't trust much of what it says :-P

By the way, should I delete this question given that it was just a matter of finding the right dictionary? Or should I leave it up, since a lot of dictionaries don't seem to have 出元? I don't know if this question counts as a "direct translation" request or not as per the site FAQ....

Please keep this, turned out this is very interesting to me...

Context aside, I'd think the meaning can be ascertained easily enough from the individual kanji. But I wouldn't have expected a kun-reading like that - not knowing that it's, apparently, a neologism.


Is it an uncommon word, a neologism, and/or slang?


Personally, I never thought 出元【でもと】 was an uncommon word or slang (until today). It may be less common than 出自 or 出所, but it was a perfectly normal word to me.

According to BCCWJ, it's a surprisingly rare word! Excluding false positives like 排出元 or 差出元, there was only one hit ("情報の出元"). However, it should be noted that BCCWJ does not contain neologisms after 2005 (it knows nothing about スマホ, for example).

On Yomiuri Shimbun's full text search (ヨミダス), 出元 is extremely rare. It's used only once in the last 10 years ("受精卵などの出元", 2019/3/3). However, this data comes from a single company, so the influence of internal proofreading engines or a list of prohibited words cannot be ruled out.

On the other hand, it's very easy to find many real examples of 出元 from various serious sources, for example this and this. Even an editor of a well-known dictionary used it in this article (written in 2009).

According to Google Trends:

This may suggest that the use of 出元 has rapidly increased in the last 20 years and it's now slightly more common than 出所. However, I don't know how Google Trends handles false positives, so I cannot say this result is truly trustworthy.

In full-text searches on Twitter (X), 出所 (even after excluding false-positives like 刑務所から出所後) seems to be several times more common than 出元, but both are common enough.

Some IME can convert でもと to 出元, but 出元 is also a surname, so this doesn't prove 出元 is a common noun.


In conclusion, at least in my perception, this is a completely common word today, and there is no problem using it for the meaning of "origin (of information, rumor, drugs, ...)". However, the fact that it's not listed in many dictionaries (yet) is undeniable, so it might be wise to be cautious when using it, especially in formal settings.
